# How to get selected edges length?

Tags: modeling, measurement

I have a female model and I want to know her waist width, so I select the edge loop, then use what tool? Is this only possible with python?

Answer (score 22):

### Update

I recommend using the newer [measureit addon](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/measureit) instead.

To measure the sum of the length of a bunch of edges like this:

1. Select the edges
2. Set the Sum group in *Tool Shelf > Measurit > Tools*
3. Click *Segment* in *Tool Shelf > Measurit > Tools*

[image]

Now the total length of those edges will be displayed at the bottom of the Measureit panel in the properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Be aware that addons have [no reliable way to track vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5541/599), so if you modify the mesh your measurements may go awry.

---

### Original answer

You could use the [new Ruler/Protractor tool](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching/Ruler_and_Protractor) located in the *3D view > Tool Shelf > Ruler/Protractor*

[image]

Note that this was just [added in Blender 2.67](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Print_Tools).

Comment: This thing is a pain to use, but just so everyone knows, use left click to place one end, then without letting go, drag a little way. Release the left mouse, then left click on one end of the line, hold down control and snap it to a desired vertice. Then release again and left click on the other end, THEN hold down control and move it to another vertice. It you don't press control after left click you will create another ruler. Took me way too long to figure out how to use this.

Comment: Is the Ruler/Protractor even an appropriate answer to the question? When I use it, it only measures the direct distance between two vertices, which does not solve the problem at all. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @mdomino I thought the OP wanted to know exactly that; the distance between two vertices. I've added an answer for the other possible interpretation I see, namely the circumference.

Comment: @gandalf3 Oh, I'm sorry, only now I realize that the OP was trying to find the waist *width* and not the circumference. However, the title of the question implies the opposite, so I am not even sure, what he wanted. :D Searching for "Blender combined edge length" brought me here, so I think it will be helpful for other people to have the circumference included in the answer, especially since MeasureIt apparently can be used for both. Additional info: You'll need at least version 1.5 of the addon (was looking around for the sum function with my outdated 1.4.1 version).

Answer (score 7):

I recently updated an older script that does this:
https://gist.github.com/zeffii/3839812

Rather than poling automatically, you press sum when you need to know the combined lengths, this also takes into account the blender unit settings.

[image]

- It also has a copy to clipboard function.

fair warning: it reports local measurements only at the moment. ( i should update that soon so you don't have to apply scale )

Comment: This script does not work anymore in Blender 2.77 (and according to a comment on the github page already in 2.75).

Comment: And I can now confirm that this works in 2.74. I'll upvote this answer, as this is the only one that actually solved the problem at hand (even though it would be more convenient of course, if the script could be used in the most recent Blender version :) ).

Comment: It says "ImportError: No module named 'space_view3d_panel_measure'" when I try to enable the addon. So in the end I am unable to enable it.

Comment: `space_view3d_panel_measure`  is not included in a standard Blender distribution, download from [buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and you'll get a scripts folder called addons_contrib, it includes that python file..

Comment: Gives me the same error. "ImportError: No module named 'space_view3d_panel_measure'"

Comment: download from buildbot and take the file from scripts/addons_contrib/space_view3d_panel_measure and install that first, then the module will be available for my script. ( this lets me re-use all the blender units / conversion code)

Comment: else.. use the measure_it addon suggested by gandalf :) worth the time.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to have to first enable an addon in your preferences called *Measure Panel*.

Next, go to the 3D view and press <kbd>N</kbd>. Scroll down to the very bottom and press the activate button on the Measure panel. Check *Edge Length*, select your edge loop and press *Update Selection*. The length slider will update with the length of your edge loop.

Comment: This does not seem to exist anymore in Blender 2.77.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for just one edges length, as opposed to the whole edge loop.

For posterity, in blender 3.1 you can show edge lengths by using the options in the 'Viewport Overlays' dialogue, which is one of the drop down boxes at the top right of the 3D viewport. It looks like two circles overlapping. There are some checkboxes down the bottom under 'Measurement':

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If you get strange readings (like I did), then you might want to 'apply scale' first.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 4.0 the *Edge Length* tick box has moved to the new *Mesh Edit Mode Overlays* dropdown menu. You need to be in *Edit Mode* to see this menu.

[image: Edit Length]

Answer (score 0):

Go to 3d view (Layout), enable snap to edges (magneet thing in top) and use Measure tool (M), it will auto-snap to edges and you will easly (at least i hope so) be able to put it on start&end of edge