# Spherical to Cube

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I know there's a option to make cubic meshes more spherical using *Mesh > Transform > To Sphere* but is there an option to do the opposite? Like *Mesh > Transform > To Cube*?

Comment: I don't see any quick way to do it

Comment: Hello and welcome. you need to explain more what you are after. I'm not sure what you mean by "making cubic meshes more Spherical", if you mean SUbdivision surface, then it's not like is making cubes into spheres, is more like adding subdivision to smooth the mesh

Comment: You mean something other than a Cast modifier in Shape—Cuboid mode? Can you show a visual example of what you need?

Comment: @Kuboå he means the opposite of *Mesh > Transform > To Sphere*. He is asking if there is a method to do *Mesh > Transform > To Cube*.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I see, I thought they were exactly the same, but now that I checked, the mesh transform seems to work a little bit better than the modifier. Still though, a *To Cube* transform would probably look like Cast modifier in Cuboid mode in the end, I think? We could come up with a solution if we knew what we're trying to achieve.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42092/how-to-make-a-circular-set-of-verticies-square

Comment: Swap over the keyframes? :D

Comment: We should probably let the user explain whats the main goal of the question

Comment: Here is another way:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiPZIvxoghc It is using a Shrinkwrap modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender 3.4; add a sphere; add a Subdivision modifier to smooth and add geometry to sphere; add Cast modifier to sphere; set cast modifier shape to cuboid; change the factor value to morph from sphere to cube; add a smooth modifier to smooth out the sphere geometry some more.
[image: sphere-to-cube]

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you!  Now can I apply this method to any mesh? For example, could I make say, the corner of the rim of a thick cylinder, into a more cubic or cornered shape?

Comment: There is more than one way to make any mesh corner sharper or more "cubic"/cornered. I suggest you look into how to set the bevel weight on edges and/or the bevel modifier as well has how edge position controls the interpolation between edges with the subdivision modifier.