# How make visible grid cell size

Tags: 3d-view

Blender view port doesn't display scale (cell size) of the grid.

Grid cell changes depending on zoom in/out (1 mm, 10 mm, 100mm, etc) .

I haven't found an option nor a plugin.

Without knowing current scale it's hard to estimate object size.

Answer (score 6):

### **Grid subdivision**

You can avoid progressive subdivision of the grid by setting the **Subdivision** parameter to 1. The scale of the grid is in the **Scale** field: it's a multiplier for your current unit.

You can find the parameters in the Display panel of the Properties panel of the 3D view:

[image]

[image]

I never heard of a plugin capable of printing the coordinates of the grid. it would probably not be very easy to work with, but there are around lots of plugin/tools that can help you in measuring distances, such as:

- Mesh Display Info (edge length, angle...)
- Transform panel (for the global/local coordinates),
- Ruler/Protractor tool
- Measure-it add-on
- and many other...

See for example:  [How to get selected edges length?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/how-to-get-selected-edges-length)

Comment: Also if you switch to using Unit scale system the current scale of the grid cells dependant on the zoom will be displayed in the top left corner (below the ortho preset name).