# How would I set a precise width of a road comprised of multiple edges?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I have a road shrink-wrapped to a terrain created by using the OpenSteetMap add-on.

In object mode, the dimensions cover the entire range of the terrain that the road covers. The dimensions report the width and breadth of the road network on the terrain.

I would like to set the width of the road segments in the overall road network.

Scale and Extrude don't seem to be the answer.  I have been going through a few books and on-line courses and have not found a solution.

Is there a modifier or other transform that can be used to set the width of the one or more individual road segments in Edit mode?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use a curve which will keep the segments of consistent size.

1.) Create the curve:

[image]

Create a plane for the road surface (although you could use a cube) and loop cut it multiple times (the more the merrier) and scale it out:
[image]

Add the ***Curve*** modifier to the plane and select the curve.  You can also scale it to the desired length:
[image]

Finally, use the ***[MeasureIt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/how-to-get-selected-edges-length)*** addon (included with Blender) and proportional editing to get the segment the exact width you want.
[image]

Comment: @DougKimzey - You're very welcome.  Semper Fi

Comment: @DougKimzey Don't just thank in the comments, upvote instead. And if the answer solved your problem consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Smooth modifier with a vertex group to control how much the modifier affects the mesh:

[image: vertex group control]

Then, you paint the vertex group to adjust the width:

[image: vertex group painting]