# Straighten vertices along a line without changing line lengths

Tags: measurement

I need to use the circumference of a shape to calculate its height with that circumference as my physical reference. I have a cross section of the shape isolated, but it's a lot vertices in a pretty irregular shape. Is there any way to have them all automatically straighten out without changing the distances between each vertex?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: If you want to find the total length of the perimeter of your cross-section,  (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/how-to-get-selected-edges-length) might help