# How do I get the inch measurement around this cup?

Tags: units, measurement

In the scene panel I've selected Inches as my units but I get this 463thou symbol instead. Anyone who knows what I'm overlooking, let me know. Asking for a friend.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/how-to-get-selected-edges-length

Comment: Thousanths of an inch.  eg 500thou is 500 / 1000 or half an inch.  Not sure if there is a way to put it 0.5 inches mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think once it goes below 1" it automatically reads thousandths. One thing that could be done is turn units back to None. This issue seems to have been fixed in 2.8 ,but doesn't help in 2.79.

None in 2.79

[image: None in 2.79]

Inches in 2.8

[image: Inches in 2.8]